# Chrome CSS blur filter bleeding through modals

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, chromium

I am using the webkit blur filter on images in my application. On Chrome (and Chrome only, from what I can tell), whenever I pop up a Modal and do some sort of mouse-over event on anything in the modal, the blur from the the image seems to bleed through the modal, as if the z-index is greater on the blurred filter (though I know it isn't).

Has anyone else ran into this issue before? I have Googled it and can't find any information on it.

Comment: Having this too. Tried adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)`, but no dice.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Here's a screenshot: http://cloud.avandamiri.com/image/1T0w2b2A3i31.

Comment: Has anyone had any luck in coming up with a solution for this? Running into the same issue.

Comment: Still nothing, eh? Lame.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but here's my solution for the bleeding problem.See the [plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/Qiu5ifaBda77NFEh6zlV/preview).

The key part is using

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
overflow: hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a long-shot here, but maybe try adding an overflow:hidden to the element it overflowing out of - along with a set width and height (http://jsfiddle.net/kerr325/o9mkpme9/):

```
.your-element {
    height:120px;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't going to fix the issue. It's not a problem of anything 'bleeding' outside of a container, but more of an issue of something bleeding through something behind it.